# How can I unpack four variables from a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list:

```
varlist = ['1', 'King', 't', '1']
```

I'm trying to unpack these four variables in a `for` loop;

```
for var1, var2, var3, var4 in varlist:
    post += len(var1)-len(var3)
    post *= len(var2)/len(var4)
```

When I run this loop, I get the following:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't actually do this. There's a quick hack to make it work the way you think it will, but ultimately what you're trying to do doesn't work.  Here's the quick hack:

```
varlist = ['1', 'King', 't', '1']
for var1, var2, var3, var4 in [varlist]: # note the brackets
    post += len(var1)-len(var3)
    post *= len(var2)\len(var4) # note that this line fails, because \ isn't /
```

The reason you can't do this is that a `for` loop iterates through each element in an iterable and assigns that value to whatever you tell it to. In this case, the first element in `varlist` is `'1'`, not `('1','King','t','1')`. By doing `for <stuff> in [varlist]` you wrap your current `varlist` in another list, and iterate on that instead. The first element of THAT is `['1','King','t','1']`, which is unpackable into `var1, var2, var3, var4`.

I'd strongly recommend rethinking your design, however, if this is really what you want to do. This sounds great if you have a lot of `varlist`s, otherwise just do:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = varlist # unpack without the loop
post += len(var1) - len(var3)
post *= len(var2) / len(var4)
```

Answer (score 8):

Unpacking is different from iteration. You need to do this:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = varlist
post += len(var1)-len(var3)
post *= len(var2)/len(var4)
```

No loop is needed here.

Comment: @Blckknght - it's not subtracting strings, it's subtracting their length. The `\` is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you don't want unpack, you want a way to group the list, and access the individual elements of the grouping which can be done with [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

post = 0

varlist = ['1', 'King', 't', '1', 'lol', 'newbs', 'money', 'plox']

print list(grouper(varlist, 4))

# Prints: [('1', 'King', 't', '1'), ('lol', 'newbs', 'money', 'plox')]

for var1, var2, var3, var4 in grouper(varlist, 4):
    post += len(var1)-len(var3)
    post *= len(var2)/len(var4)

print post

# Prints: -2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
varlist = ['1', 'King', 't', '1']

for i,j,k,l in zip(*[iter(varlist)]*4):
    print i,j,k,l
1 King t 1
```

The *4 is the amount of elements you want, if you had a list like `varlist=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10]`

It will zip four elements in a step of 4 giving the output:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

The elements in your list must be a multiple of the variables you are assigning them to or you will not get all the elements as shown in the ouput above.

Comment: Yuck. `zip(*[iter(iterable)]*N)` is amazing when you know what it does, but @anon already posted an itertools grouper answer and yours has no comments on it. The OP used a backslash for division, there's no chance in hell that they'll understand `zip`, `iter`, or `[]*N`, much less `*` or all of them put together!

Comment: I think this is way too complex for easy unpacking. No need to `iter`, multiply list or `zip` when it can be done without a loop.

Comment: @AdamSmith, does it not answer the question? And I answered almost the same time as anon.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham as posted, this post applied: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality

Comment: @Adam Smith I got a call on my cell, I was going to flush out the answer. I never leave code only answers but I understand your point.